# Dois campos de uma tabela associada a Um campo de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema que nele tenho um tabela chamada **equipes** , e outra tabela é chamada de **posts**.

```
Tabela equipes
id, nome, foto

Tabela posts
id, titulo, id_time_1, id_time_2
```

O que eu realmente queria e tentei fazer e não tive exito é o seguinte.
pegar o do id_time_1 e id_time_2, ser associada em apenas o id da tabela equipes, tentei o INNER JOIN e não tive exito.

```
SELECT * FROM `equipes`
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `equipes`.`id` = `posts`.`id_time_1`
AND `equipes`.`id` = `posts`.`id_time_2`
```

Comment: qual é a finalidade de `id_time_1` e `id_time_2`? isso tem cara de precisar de uma nova tabela ...

Comment: Ex: a tabela equipe tem dois registro.
id = 1, nome = Barcelona e foto = upada normalmente. e o outro registro.
id = 2, nome = Real Madrid e foto = upada normalmente.
E a tabela posts tem um registro. id = 1, titulo = Post teste, id_time_1 = 1, id_time_2 = 2. como que eu teria q fzr essa consulta

Comment: Acho que entendi, poderia colocar o select que tentou na pergunta?

Comment: aqui o select que tentei. SELECT * FROM `equipes` INNER JOIN `posts` ON `equipes`.`id` = `posts`.`id_time_1` AND `equipes`.`id` = `posts`.`id_time_2`

Comment: Você fazer uma query só não seria melhor? Uma vez tendo os dados do post, basta fazer um select para cada id_time. Acho mais limpo para manutenção do que os joins aqui embaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi o que você quer é:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`
JOIN `equipes` AS `e1` ON `posts`.`id_time_1` = `e1`.`id`
JOIN `equipes` AS `e2` ON `posts`.`id_time_2` = `e2`.`id`
```

A sua estratégia de recuperação dos dados está invertida. Você quer o `post` e associar o nome times dos relacionados a ele. Então é preciso que o select principal use a tabela `post` e use um join próprio com `equipe` para cada time.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu mt meu problema!

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando INNER JOIN então o select só vai te retornar os resultados caso as condições apresentadas sejam verdadeiras.

Você disse que os registros possuem os seguinte valores:

**Tabela equipes:**

id = 1, nome = Barcelona e foto = upada normalmente

id = 2, nome = Real Madrid e foto = upada normalmente

**Tabela posts:**

id_time_1 = 1

id_time_2 = 2

**O seu select:**

SELECT * FROM `equipes`
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `equipes`.`id` = `posts`.`id_time_1`
AND `equipes`.`id` = `posts`.`id_time_2`

Perceba que existe um erro de lógica, pois o valor de `id_time_1 = 1` e `id_time_2 = 2`. Então quando comparado com o id 1 da tabela equipes a primeira condição sera verdadeira e a segunda falsa (resultando em falso e não trara nada). Quando comparado com o id 2 da tabela equipes a primeira condição sera falsa (então nem caíra na segunda e não trara nada também).

Existem várias maneiras de se corrigir isso, Mas pela simplicidade e facilidade eu adicionaria um campo id_equipes na tabela post e associaria esse campo no select. Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM equipes e
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.id_equipes = e.id
```

Comment: Alan, já tinha feito dessa forma e também, não tinha dado certo, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela disponibilidade em entender meu problema :D

Comment: Para fazer desta forma vc deveria criar o campo id_equipes na tabela posts com o respectivo id da tabela equipes para cada posts. Assim funcionaria. Mas de qualquer forma, o mais importante é resolver o problema e n necessariamente como! ;)